# Flex: Are unused module project files included in the module swf's?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, optimization, flash

Currently optimizing an application at work. There are many files in some of the module projects that are not used by the exported (release build) Module.swf's. Are these unused files included in the swf's?

What about unused imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no reference to them in your code the no, they will not be included in the exported swf. The compiler is smart enough to check for unused imports.

If you're using the mxmlc to compile then you can set the -link-report flag to true to get a list of dependencies and their sizes.  It generates a rather ugly XML file, but see this article for more info and a nice way to view it. http://blog.iconara.net/2007/02/25/visualizing-mxmlcs-link-report/

Comment: Ran the -link-report: it does'nt show any internally linked files, just the Flash/Flex lib files and any externally linked swf/swc classes, but i'll take your word for it they're not included:) It did get me looking into using the linkReport.xml file from the main app as the param for load-externs in the module compiler options (reduced module size by 15%)

Comment: I'm glad it put you on the right track. If you really want to squeeze every last byte I'd think about removing the metadata and product info tags from the compiled swf. They're pretty useless for module files. You probably won't save a lot, but it mounts up if you have lots of modules.